# RevMob doesn't work

Tags: ios, revmob

When I trying to show fullscreen ad, I get the following message:

"[RevMob] No Ads available for this device. "

It worked fine before, but now ad doesn't appears. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen due to lack of ads for your device,
it should be a temporary issue.

On newer skd version the message was changed to something like this:

[RevMob] No Ads available for this device/country at this moment

Answer (score 0):

add a proper key , check the spelling, App ID .